# Why is my Bones moving, but not my mesh?

Tags: mesh, bones, weight-painting

I'm quite new to blender, and modeling in general. Can someone explain to me why this happens?[image]

Basically my issue is that when I bend the bones, the mesh itself does not follow it and instead causes a weird distortion on the mesh, such as stretching or flattening things such as fingers.

[image]

Comment: In general the Parent With Automatic Weights won't work fine for the hand and you need to correct manually (remove all these vertices from any vertex group, select the vertices you want, select the vertex group they should be part of, click on Assign)

Comment: @moonboots thank you, i will try this. but when i check, my hand bones have two for each bone. what should i do for that? do i assign it over the ones i made or the other ones i didnt.

Comment: You need to check the ones that have the Deform option enabled (in Edit or Pose mode, select the bone and go in the Bone Properties panel > Deform)

Comment: @moonboots all the bones in the hand have deform enabled, When I try to delete either copy of the Vertex group, they come back. I tried assigning the pinky to both of the groups, which sort of fixed the weird folding, but the weight paint stretched out the finger. I also noticed after I assigned the fingers, the weightpaint still applied to multiple Vertex groups.

Comment: You first need to remove all the hand vertices from all groups (Remove from All Groups function on the right of the Vertex Groups list). Then assign them to the vertex group that have the name of the bone that is supposed to control them

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't just add images of your issue, textually describe it in detail as well. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @moonboots this fixed the issue with the fingers, thank you. i tried reassigning the vertices for the palm/wrist and the hand still does the same in the first image, but the fingers now bend perfectly. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Hello! Sorry, when I made the post I had no idea what was going on as this is my first model. I now know some more terms and can edit the post as I've trial and errored a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I figured out thanks to the help of @moonboots , so thank you for your replies.

What I did was I went into the Vertices

(Mesh > Edit Mode)

and selected the ones on the hands and removed it from all groups

(Highlight Vertices > Object Data on the right side > Pick Vertex group (i.e. Pinky_Finger1 for the Pinky knuckle) > Right arrow next to the Vertex groups > Remove from all groups.)

Then I manually applied them onto the Vertex groups.

(Highlight Vertices > Go to corresponding Vertex Group > Assign)

Then I tweaked it over and over

(Instead of Remove from all groups, I used Remove from active group, which removed it all from the individual group instead of the entire vertices being removed which could cause problems with overlapping applied vertices on multiple groups! Use remove from all groups if the selected vertex is highlighted on another bone!)

Which... took a very long time, mostly trial and error with figuring it out but I was able to successfully move and pose the arm!

[image]